# How to run the powershell code for all system drives?

Tags: powershell

At the moment the code runs only against drive **C:** I would like to run/apply the code below  to all existing system drives the their sub-folders contents, i.e. **C:\ D:\ E:\ , etc. Any suggestion on how to achieve this? If you need me to clarify my question, just ask. (**I want the *$dir* to substitute for all system drive roots**).

```
$dir = "c:\"
#this is main client-side file scanning code for use on client computers
$count = @{}
$size = @{}
$hostname = @{}
gci $dir -recurse |%{
[int]$count[$_.extension] += 1
[int64]$size[$_.extension] += $_.length
}
$results = @()
$count.keys | sort |% {
$result = ""|select extension,count,size,hostname
$result.extension = $_
$result.count = $count[$_]
$result.size = [math]::round($size[$_] /1Gb, 3)
$result.hostname = $(get-content env:computername)
$results += $result
}
$results | ft -auto

$dirName = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\${Env:ComputerName}"
if (!(Test-Path $dirName)) { mkdir $dirName }

$results | sort-object -property size -Descending | select-object -first 30| export-csv c:\"$env:computername-$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm)".csv

$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:#A987CC;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;.center { margin:auto; width:70%; };}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#99CCFF}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


$results | sort-object -property size -Descending | select-object -first 30 | ConvertTo-Html extension,count,size, hostname "$a" -title "JUST" -body "TOP 30 FILES" | 
Set-Content C:\inetpub\wwwroot\${Env:ComputerName}\"$env:computername-$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm)".htm
```

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive. What portion of the code do you want to search all drives? What specifically do you want it to do? You aren't looking at the whole of `C:` here in the first place - just a single user's profile directory and the computer's `wwwroot`..

Comment: @alroc my bad. I've corrected the code in the first line now. I want the **$dir** to substitute for all system drive roots. now how to do it I don't know. I'm new to the Powershell.

Comment: @alroc I'm trying to use **Get-PSDrive | select root** in the first live to substitute all disk drive roots with variable. but still i have errors. any suggestions?

Comment: Ok I got it sorted. So I used the first like of the answer and added the \ to it, and it worked! as follows: `$dirA = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "Drivetype=3"|select -expandproperty deviceid;
$dirB ="\"
$dir = $dirA +=$dirB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have it, all you really needed was to get a listing of all the physical drives on the computer and then loop through it.

A couple other notes:

- I removed `$results |ft -auto`. You probably had it in there as debug output.
- You do this twice: `$results | sort-object -property size -Descending | select-object -first 30`. I did it once, storing the output back into `$results`. Multiple trips of the same data through the same pipeline steps is inefficient.
- I made `$a` a [here-string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx). Easier to read & work with than concatenating strings.
- I reformatted the date string in your output files so that you can sort filenames by date.
- Don't put files in `c:\`. It's just sloppy. Find a more appropriate location.
- This will capture all folders (you aren't filtering them out). Is that desired?

  ```
  $drives = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "Drivetype=3"|select -expandproperty deviceid;

  #this is main client-side file scanning code for use on client computers
  $results = @()
  foreach ($drive in $drives){
  $count = @{}
  $size = @{}
  $hostname = @{}
  gci $drive -recurse |%{
      [int]$count[$_.extension] += 1
      [int64]$size[$_.extension] += $_.length
  }   
  $count.keys | sort |% {
      $result = ""|select extension,count,size,hostname;
      $result.extension = $_;
      $result.count = $count[$_];
      $result.size = [math]::round($size[$_] /1Gb, 3);
      $result.hostname = $(get-content env:computername);
      $results += $result;
  }
  }

  $dirName = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\${Env:ComputerName}"
  if (!(Test-Path $dirName)) { New-Item -ItemType directory $dirName }
  $results = $results|Sort-Object -property size -Descending|Select-Object -First 30;

  $results | export-csv c:\"$env:computername-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm)".csv

  $a = @"
  <style>
  BODY{background-color:#A987CC;}
  TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;.center { margin:auto; width:70%; };}
  TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#99CCFF}
  TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}
  </style>
  "@

  $results | ConvertTo-Html extension,count,size, hostname "$a" -title "JUST" -body "TOP 30 FILES" | Set-Content C:\inetpub\wwwroot\${Env:ComputerName}\"$env:computername-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm)".htm
  ```

Comment: yes, that is my target to capture all folders and files in all root directories. I  tried running your code and also just using the first line just to get all drives. But it runs too quick for the job, it seems that it doesn't actually scan all the drives and their contents. though it doesn't show any errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: thanks it worked eventually with the following modifications:``$dirA = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "Drivetype=3"|select -expandproperty deviceid;
$dirB ="\"
$dir = $dirA +=$dirB

Answer (score -1):

```
$dirA = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "Drivetype=3"|select -expandproperty deviceid
$dirB ="\"
$dir = $dirA +=$dirB
```

Comment: I guess **Vasanch** is trying to point to the exact couple of lines that had to be added to get this code working properly. He is referring to my last reply to your answer above.